# Como filtrar um DataView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, datatable, ado.net

Tenho um DataView e estou tentando fazer um filtro, onde o campo 'foto' for diferente de NULL

Tentei:

```
 dv.RowFilter = "foto <> ''";
```

Mas não filtrou.
Procurei aqui no StackOver e recomendaram:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(foto,'') <> ''";
```

tentei também:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(foto, 'Null Column') != 'Null Column'";
```

Com:
`"foto <> null"` ele não retorna nenhum resultado.

Mesma coisa, não filtra, no banco de dados ela retorna como `NULL`

*Quando faço um filtro simples do tipo*

```
dv.RowFilter = "foto ='123412341234.jpg'";
```

funciona perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio que seu problema não está no filtro, e sim quando você faz o filtro

Comment: quando faço um filtro simples tipo: dv.RowFilter = "foto ='123412341234.jpg'"; funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Então esquece o que eu falei.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código até a parte do databind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri, aliás seria o mais lógico, sendo que segue o padrão do MS SQL.
Eu tentei fazendo via formato LINQ e não funcionava.

**Somente NULL**

```
dv.RowFilter = "foto IS NULL";
```

**Somente os com registro** (not null)

```
dv.RowFilter = "foto IS NOT NULL";
```

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: O caminho mais fácil...